# Remove Ubuntu strings from Mini install

Tags: ubuntu, string

I have an assignment to remove a string from Ubuntu Mini v. 15.04. How would I remove the Ubuntu String on the top? It says "Ubuntu 15.04 hostname tty1". I just want to remove Ubuntu 15.04 string.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I don't have a GUI. This is all command line.

Comment: Are you wanting to modify the string "Ubuntu 15.04 hostname tty1"? Can you be a little more clear on what output you are wanting?

Comment: Yes, I just want to modify the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That string is set in `/etc/issue`. You can (as root) edit that file to change the message. Note that you'll have to have the getty respawn to print the new message; usually failing a few login attempts is enough (but other things will work too, such as killing it, or of course rebooting).

Comment: Thank you. How do I save the file with command line? I don't have a GUI.

Comment: @c.C You'd use a CLI text editor. The a easiest to use is probably nano.